# Excel connect to Access with low performance

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access, sql-update

My code want to query access very frequently, I use "for" for every row and check a cell's value if existed in access table. But I feel the performance is very bad. Now I'm using adodb.connection to connect to access. Sorry I cannot put code because its not in my hand. Anyone could help me about how to query a table very frequently from excel vba and with fast performance?

**EDIT:**

```
For rowNum = 2 To 1000000

'check if title exists,if yes, get ppid, if not, insert one, get ppid, and make relation in r-table
    ppID = isTitleExistReturnID(ppTitle)
    If ppID = "0" Then
        ppID = addPpReturnID(ppTitle, ppDate, ppJournal)
        paperAddedCount = paperAddedCount + 1
        isPpAdded = True
    Else
        isPpAdded = False
    End If

Next rowNum


Function isTitleExistReturnID(title As String) As String
Dim r As New ADODB.Recordset
sqlstr = "select * from paper where title = '" & title & " '"
'MsgBox sqlstr
dbConnection.Open
r.Open sqlstr, dbConnection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
If r.RecordCount < 1 Then
    dbConnection.Close
    isTitleExistReturnID = "0"
Else
    aidi = r.Fields(0).Value
    dbConnection.Close
    isTitleExistReturnID = aidi
End If
End Function

Function addPpReturnID(title As String, pubDate As String, journaL As String) As String
Dim r As New ADODB.Recordset
sqlstr = "select * from paper where (1=0)"
'MsgBox sqlstr
dbConnection.Open
r.Open sqlstr, dbConnection, adOpenKeyset, adLockOptimistic, adCmdText
r.AddNew
r.Fields(1) = title
r.Fields(2) = pubDate
r.Fields(3) = journaL
r.Update
maxid = CStr(r.Fields(0).Value)
dbConnection.Close
addPpReturnID = maxid
End Function
```

The above is part of my code:

1. check if the item is in access table
2. if YES, return its ID
3. if NO, add this item and return ID

Do it for more than 100,000 times, very low performance

Any advice will be so appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: You could use Data>Connection>Access to bring the data in Access into a refreshable table in Excel, and then just check against the table.

Comment: Depending on the number of rows in the queried table, you could load the table into memory either as a dictionary (with the "lookup" column as the key), or using something like a disconnected recordset.

Comment: @DougGlancy hi buddy, sorry I wasn't clear, please kindly check my edited part. Thanks

Comment: @TimWilliams please kindly check the added part. Sorry I wasn't clear about my question.

Comment: Typically what percentage of your lines need to be added to the database?

Comment: @TimWilliams, more than 80%, but the problem is before every insert, I have to check if it is existed already, that slows down the performance

Comment: If 80% of your lines need adding anyway, I would adjust your `addPpReturnID` function to instead of querying `where (1=0)` to query by title: if it exists you can just return the associated ID, if not you can add the record and then return the ID. Then you wouldn't need `isTitleExistReturnID` at all...

Comment: Also. if you make your DB connection object a global variable, you can just open it once before you start looping, and close it at the end when you're done.

Comment: Is your Access DB on a network drive? If so, network latency is probably killing your performance. Remember that, unlike a true database server, Access is just a file server, with the resource remote (in this case) and CPU resources local. Either find a way to bring the data store local; migrate up to a client-server architecture; or build a pipe-line processor that retrieves rows in good-sized batches asynchronously.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any [RBAR (row by agonizing row)](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/rbar--row-by-agonizing-row/) approach has the potential to be a performance challenge --- that's why it's called agonizing.

And yours is definitely RBAR because you do stuff separately for each of a million (`For rowNum = 2 To 1000000`) spreadsheet rows.  Compounding the problem is the fact that you're opening and closing ADODB objects (connections and recordsets) at least one, but sometimes twice, for each of those rows.

Try to find a set-based approach instead.  For example, if you can drive this operation from Access ...

1. Create a link to the spreadsheet.
2. Create an "unmatched" query (there is a query wizard to guide you) to select those spreadsheet rows whose `ppTitle` does not exist in the Access destination table.
3. Create an "append" query to add those unmatched rows to the Access table.

I don't know whether that outline is a suitable fit for your situation or whether it's close enough that you can adapt it.  But the more important point is to find a set-based method instead of RBAR.

Comment: +1 for suggesting attempts to avoid RBAR, and mentioning that the current approach creates database connections and queries for every row. If RBAR turned out to be absolutely necessary then at least using a persistent ADO connection and prepared statements would probably help.

Comment: Yes, good points.  I would also try DAO instead of ADO.  Within Access, I've found DAO can be significantly faster ... but I'm not sure whether it would offer the same advantage when used from Excel.